# How to sort weekdays in Power BI based on today

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

How can I sort days of week from right to left.

something like this:

[image]

This is what I have now:

[image]

I created column DayOfWeekSort but it gives me an error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your model get refreshed daily or does this have to be done entirely dynamically?

Comment: it refreshes daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `TODAY()` in a calculated column, it only updates whenever that column is recalculated (e.g. when the model is refreshed). Since you said your report is refreshed daily, this is good enough.

Try this:

```
DayOfWeekSort = MOD ( [Date] - TODAY (), 7 )
```

This gives `0` for today and increases up to a maximum of `6` and starts over.

---

As the error message says, you can't map, say, `Tuesday` to more than one value in a column to sort by, so the sorting column can't have more unique values than the column you are trying to sort.